# Why Google Guava Filter is not ignoring Case Sensitive Arraylist<String>

Tags: android, guava

I'm trying to use Google's Guava in my android app. 
I used Guava Filter in two different files. In both files I have an Arraylist of String type. In first it working great as I expected but in other code it is not working. I don't know what's wrong in my code. I have checked everything in my code but I did not understand where is the problem.
Here is my First code which is working great! :)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.addAll(arrayList);
                List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
                        list, Predicates.contains(Pattern.compile(newText,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))));
```

It is working good. It fully ignore case sensitive.
This is my Second code:

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(song_name);
        List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
                list, Predicates.contains(Pattern.compile(query,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))));
```

In the above code when I search a string that is lower case than the result appears but if the string is upper or in sentence case than it is not working. 
So, it is not ignoring case sensitive. 
Anybody know what's the problem with my code... 
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you think is "Guava Search"? Because I think I know Guava pretty well, and there's no such thing as "Guava Search"...

Comment: Ohh... actually I want to filter a arrayList using Guava liabrary

Comment: If that's what you want to do, you're doing it OK, and the issue is not in the code you show here. It's probably in another portion of your code that you haven't pasted here.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, I was trying to debug my code and I found first time filter is works but after that I don't know but it's not working. I think there is problem with my ArrayList so I log it but it show all the list :(